# CONCAT with COUNT, SUM,

Tags: doctrine-orm, count, sum, concatenation

In a complex query, I have a subquery to count/summarize children:

```
->addSelect('(SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(c.id), \'|\', SUM(c.field1), \'|\', SUM(c.field2), \'|\', SUM(c.field3)) FROM App\Entity\Child c WHERE c.parent = p.id GROUP BY c.parent)')
```

This query worked perfectly until I upgraded to the new version of Symfony (4.2) and doctrine orm 2.6.1. I got the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 25: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got 'COUNT'
```

I tried to use CAST ... AS CHAR(25) but it doesn't work (got the same error).
Anyone can help me please?

Best regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like it is regression in doctrine StringPrimary parser function.
After looking at code I have made comment with my observation in issue related to this problem (while not entierly describing it).

Essentially new function missing this part, and defaulting to error when encountering any aggregate functions:

```
            default:
            if ($this->isAggregateFunction($lookaheadType)) {
                return $this->AggregateExpression();
            }
```

PS. link to the related issue:
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/7205

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: I install [doctrine extensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) and I replace CONCAT by CONCAT_WS (DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\ConcatWs).
Best regards